# Jupyter notebooks are loading but while running there's nothing happening

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, conda

I was facing an error with Jupyter notebook to which I could not found a solution so far:

```
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='127.0.0.1:8888', method='GET', uri='/ipython/api/kernelspecs', 
line 1703, in _execute result = await result     
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Reference of this, is [mentioned here as well](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4909) [but not much helpful] - I could not update comment there as its closed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using a domain name to point to this Jupyter notebook (thorugh nginx), I didnt realize but I changed to a new domain name (since old one was expired for me) and then this error started occurring. I even have tried passing a new domain name as an argument while restarting the notebook server but the same did not help and was through above error.

> --GatewayClient.url='https://newdomain.com'

As a temporary fix, I tried putting in my local dns hosts file a mapping of old domain names pointing to the same IP address and voilla, it fixed the problem. At least it works.

While this is not a fix but locally unblocked me to access and execute my jupyter notebooks.

I will post an update if I could fix it and move to a new domain name.

Thanks,